# How to pass a vector by copy, and by reference, to a function?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

```
    int main () {
       vector <int> vectorF;
       functionX <vector<int>&, long> (vectorF, 1L);
    }

    template <typename dataTypeA, 
              typename dataTypeB> dataTypeB functionX (dataTypeA argA, 
                                                       dataTypeB argB)
    {   
    }
```

This code changes the actual values in the vector, if modified in the function definition.

What is the way to pass the vector by copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`functionX <vector<int>, long> (vectorF, 1L);`

Addind a `&` after the `vector<int>` will make the `dataTypeA` to be a reference to a vector. If you want a copy to a vector, remove the &

Comment: That was so dumb of me, to not think of that simple matter. The question deserves a downvote. :rolleyes: and thanks to you for the prompt response.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it answered your question? Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, and I don't need these reminders, I am waiting for 6 minutes to pass since can't accept the answer before that. :)

Comment: By mentioning `<vector<int>,long>` you are not really taking advantage of `template` facility. :)

Comment: Yes type inference is really a neat feature and should be used in this case. I agree with you @iammilind

Answer (score 4):

Simply call the function as,

```
functionX (vectorF, 1L);  // ok! explicit function calling isn't needed
```

However, as a side not I would like to mention that making a copy of a whole `vector` just for a function doesn't make much sense. You can simply change the function definition to,

```
template <typename dataTypeA, typename dataTypeB>
dataTypeB functionX (const dataTypeA& argA, dataTypeB argB)
{                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ const reference 
}
```

if you are using this `vector` for reading purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, alas too late.

Comment: @Anisha, make sure that you **really** need to make a copy of the `vector`. Because, I have seldom seen such usage. Have explained that in the answer.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, but I just wanted to know how to do it. :)

Comment: Then in which cases `<vector<int>,long>` is supposed to be used?

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense for vector, but it's a feature that's in the language because it works for any class and there may be classes a copy does make sense for.